# How to find the middle x in ANY plot in R using grconvertX?

Tags: r, plot

I'm wondering given ANY plot drawn using **BASE R** (i.e., without any `layout()` or `mfcol()` or `mfrow()`) (see below for an example), how can one find the "X" coordinate of a point that would be always exactly in the middle of that plot (suppose "Y" for the point is arbitrary)?

I think `grconvertX` is designed to do this but I'm not sure how it exactly works (I appreciate a good explanation on `grconvertX`) as it has many settings (see below).

```
plot(1, t = "n", log = "x")

mean( grconvertX(0:1, "user") )
mean( grconvertX(0:1, "nic")  )
mean( grconvertX(0:1, "nfc")  )
mean( grconvertX(0:1, "ndc")  )
mean( grconvertX(0:1, "npc")  )
mean( grconvertX(0:1, "device") )
```

Comment: you were close with "npc" ~ "normalized plot coordinates" `points(grconvertX(.5, 'npc'), grconvertY(.5, 'npc'), col = 2)` and as indicated in the answer below, `par('usr')` and `c(grconvertX(0:1, 'npc'), grconvertY(0:1, 'npc'))` should be identical (if the axes were not logged) or `c(log10(grconvertX(0:1, 'npc')), grconvertY(0:1, 'npc'))` if they were

Comment: @rawr, I like d.b., also feel bad not being able to accept and upvote your answer as d.b also knows I was familar with par(`usr`) but I was more interested in `grconvertX`. Also give us an intuition as to how these various settings in `grconvertX` (i.e., "nic", "ndc" ...) really work in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `par("usr")`. Read more at `?par`. Because you are using `log = x`, you have to raise the `par("usr")[1:2]` to `10`.

```
plot(1, type = "n", log = "x")
points(x = 10^mean(par("usr")[1:2]), y = mean(par("usr")[3:4]), pch = 19)
```